# Is the Infinity Gauntlet still usable after the events of Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, the-infinity-gauntlet

At the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*, Thanos

> snaps his fingers and wipes out half of the population of the universe.

When we last see him, he's sitting in a hut where he smiles and it looks like his entire left hand is severely damaged. It goes all the way to the left side of his hand, with the Infinity Gauntlet looking like it has about one good use left in it before it falls apart.

So can he actually use it or even one of the stones, for that matter?

Comment: @Valorum Also the [*alleged*] use of the Time stone to reverse Stormbreaker's gash on his chest.

Comment: The question seems to be under the Future works policy as the answer might be revealed in the next Avengers' movie. @Valorum, Thanos may have used the stones directly without the gauntlet's aid (remember, the Red skull was transported off Earth by the Space stone and even the Dark Elves used the reality stone without the gauntlet.) So the gauntlet might be damaged, but the stones would still be intact.

Comment: I've voted to close as this question falls foul of our [future works policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based). The end of the film states that Thanos will return and we'll obviously learn the disposition of his gauntlet when that happens.

Comment: True, although might the comics offer some insight?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite- OP has asked for movie answers.

Answer (score 3):

He can certainly use the Space Stone, as that’s how he got to the hut in the first place.

As for all the other stones individually, or collectively for finger-snap purposes, we don’t know yet. There’s no obvious reason for the other stones not to work individually, and we’ve seen them wielded without the gauntlet in other movies.

Story-telling-wise, it would probably be a bit tricky for the next movie if Thanos still had the power to make anything happen just by clicking his fingers, so it wouldn’t be a shock if the particularly-beat-up-looking gauntlet no longer worked. However, in [the original *Infinity Gauntlet* comic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_Gauntlet#Plot), the be-gemmed gauntlet is still useable after it kills half the universe.

---

***AND NOW, AFTER AVENGERS: ENDGAME — THE BIG REVEAL!!!***

> Yup, still works.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is the correct answer given current knowledge

Comment: @Timpanus - I downvoted because I don't find the answer useful. I'm also averse to people answering questions that are clearly off-topic, especially when the entire point of the "[future works policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)" is that non-answers like this will be superseded with higher quality ones when the sequel comes out.